# Attribute Selectors for styled-componnets

Tags: styled-components

Is it possible to use attribute selectors when using sytled-components?

```
&:hover, &[active='true']{
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 16px 0px rgba(255,63,23,0.87),
}
```

the idea is that then I have the following

```
<Button active />
```

Otherwise I have to duplicate the code and it becomes much more uglier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `css` helper and some interpolations to avoid duplicating the code:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'; 

const hoverStyles = css`
  transform: translateY(-4px);
  box-shadow: 0 7px 16px 0px rgba(255,63,23,0.87);
`;

const Component = styled.div`
  // If the component is hovered add the hoveredStyles
  &:hover { ${hoverStyles} }
  // If the active property is set add the hoverStyles
  ${props => props.active && hoverStyles}
`
```

We don't plan to implement any special behaviour with attribute selectors and props like in your code idea. We want to avoid diverging from actual CSS as much as possible to avoid confusion, highlighting/parsing issues etc.

Lots of things you might want to add special magic syntax in the CSS string for are possible with a touch of JavaScript! (see above)

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense. I didn't know about the css`` magic :)

Comment: How can attribute selectors not be actual CSS ?

Comment: How would you target a child with an attribute selector?

Comment: _"styled-components generates an actual stylesheet with classes, and attaches those classes to the DOM nodes of styled components via the className prop."_ I presume this is also the case with the CSS helper? https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#existing-css